# 'I have been queuing up for too long'

Tags: perfect-constructions

May I ask if it is correct and natural to say

> I have been queuing up for too long.

to describe the condition in which I have been waiting for a long time in a queue?

If not, how can this sentence be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

I would rephrase it slightly, "I have [or I've] been queued up for too long."

The "-ing" (present tense) suggests you are in the act of getting into the queue.  You are already in the queue, so you use the past tense, "-ed" instead.

That said, in the United States (I'm not sure where you are), the word, "queue" is rarely used.  On this side of the Atlantic, we would typically say, "I've been in line for too long." Saying "queued up" might get a sideways glance as to why you're using an uncommon term. It's not incorrect though. You can be confident that you're using it correctly.

Comment: Agreed.  "in line for too long" or "waiting in line too long" sounds more natural to this American.  Although in NYC, we say **on** line!

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to announce that you felt you had been queueing too long and are now compelled to leave the line or are making a complaint to someone, I would simply say,
"I've been queueing too long", implying the situation is unacceptable.

(even though, being British, I would never actually complain but I am not good at queueing, so would probably slink away sadly, making a tiny "tut" noise as I went)

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers! I'm neither from the US nor the UK. It is great to learn about the both sides' Eng usage! :)